# Express.js validating Array with JOI

Tags: node.js, express, joi

I'm trying to validate an array with `joi` on an `express` back-end, but I keep getting an error even if I pass a correct array.

Consider the following, where I'm passing an array of strings in my `POST` request in postman:
`myArrayKey:["stringA", "stringB"]`

This is a valid array and should be allowed, but `JOI` is giving me an error. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Here's my code:

```
exports.mySchema = Joi.object({
    myArrayKey: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).required()
});
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @StockOverflaw Input needs to be an array. I realised that it's actually because I'm sending the data as form encoded instead of json. When I send as JSON, it works fine.